# How to select particular menu position in wordpress?

Tags: menus, navigation

I have 3 menu positions primary, side and footer in functions.php. ho do i select side menu position and add condition to that menu only?

```
function abc_menus() {
register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu' ),//Main Menu
        'side'=>__('Our Holidays'),//Menu on side
        'footer'=>__('Footer '),//First Footer Menu

    )
);
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'abc_menus' );
```

Answer (score 0):

In your theme file place below code there where you need.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'side' ) ); ?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus#Display_Menus_on_Theme

Answer (score 0):

Call the wp_nav_menu like this:

```
<div>
        <?php 
        wp_nav_menu(array(
            'menu_class' => 'GIVE MENU A CLASS',        
            'menu' => 'MENU NAME'
        )
        );
        ?>
    </div>
```